# How to perform Row update in WinUI3 Datagrid

Tags: winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I am new to WinUI and using `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls` for my WinUI3 application. Where I am using Datagrid. One of the columns is generating like follows:

```
 <controls:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding MessageId}" Header="Id" />
```

I also have a Button column generated for the action in the grid as follows:

```
 <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Click="SendAsync" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=MessageId}">Send</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
```

My problem is that this button should only be visible based on the column "Status" from the Source. After searching on the internet I could not find any solution. I used to use `row_update` on the WinForm application where we can use conditional visibility based on any cell value.

Please suggest to me how to overcome this kind of problem for conditional visibility/ `Row_update` like functionality in WinUI3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a **Converter** and control the `Button`'s `Visibility` property like this.

**BoolToVisibilityConverter.cs**

```cs
public class BoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return ((bool)value) is true
            ? Visibility.Visible
            : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

**Your DataGrid**

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <helpers:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

```xml
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action">                    
    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button
                Click="SendAsync"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Path=MessageId}"
                Visibility="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>>
                Send
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew I tried this. seems like a simple straightforward solution but After I apply this solution it's creating a Parsing error !!  :(

Comment: It works. I actually created a sample code to check it. My first guess is that you are not declaring the ``BoolToVisibilityConverter`` as a **Resource**. Take a look at this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter?view=winrt-22621#examples

Comment: ok, I'll check it.

Comment: Thanks your Idea works. Yes, I didn't create that Resource. But after declaring the resource followed by you given link it solved